# Не правильно работает шифр

Tags: javascript

Делаю шифр Виженера. Проблема моя в том что он шифрует не правильно. Он должен зашифровать строку "ЗАШИФРОВАТЬ СТРОКУ МЕТОДОМ ВИЖЕНЕРА" с ключом "ЗАЩИТА" и зашифрованный текст должен быть "пассжрцвщыо сързуё ммтзмбм йианаеша.", а он мне выдает "юрбацаетйкю бйачвх ььвчьрь щшпэпхзр.". Я проверял в функцию `crypt` приходят правильные коды ключа и текста. В чем заключается проблема?

```
function encrypt(paremeter) {
    var key = '';
    var textElem = '';
    if (paremeter == false) {
        key = filterKey(document.getElementById("encrypted_key").value);
        textElem = document.getElementById("encrypted_input");
        textElem = document.getElementById("encrypted_input");
    } else {
        key = filterKey(document.getElementById("decryption_key").value);
        textElem = document.getElementById("decryption_input");
        textElem = document.getElementById("decryption_input");
    }

    if (key.length == 0) {
        alert("У ключа нет букв");
        return;
    }

    if (paremeter) {
        for (var i = 0; i < key.length; i++)
            key[i] = (32 - key[i]) % 32;
    }

    textElem.value = crypt(textElem.value, key);
}

// Возвращает результат шифрования с заданным ключом.
function crypt(input, key) {
    //console.log(key);
    var output = '';
    for (var i = 0, j = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        var c = input.charCodeAt(i);
        if (isUppercase(c)) {
            console.log(c);
            output += String.fromCharCode((c - 1071 - 32 + key[j % key.length]) % 32 + 1071);
            console.log(output);
            j++;
        } else if (isLowercase(c)) {
            output += String.fromCharCode((c - 1103 - 32 + key[j % key.length]) % 32 + 1103);
            console.log(output);
            j++;
        } else {
            output += input.charAt(i);
        }
    }
    return output;
}

/* Возвращает массив чисел, каждый в диапазоне [0, 33], представляющий данный ключ.
 * Ключ нечувствителен к регистру, а не-буквы игнорируются.
 */
function filterKey(key) {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < key.length; i++) {
        var c = key.charCodeAt(i);
        if (isLetter(c)) {
            result.push(c - 1103 - 32 % 32 + 1103);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

// Проверяет, является ли указанный код символа буквой.
function isLetter(c) {
    return isUppercase(c) || isLowercase(c);
}

// Проверяет, является ли указанный код символа заглавной буквой.
function isUppercase(c) {
    return 1040 <= c && c <= 1071; // 1040 - код символа для 'A' и 1071 для 'Я'.
}

// Проверяет, является ли указанный код символа строчной буквой.
function isLowercase(c) {
    return 1072 <= c && c <= 1103; // 1072 - код символа для 'а' и 1103 для 'я'.
}
```

Comment: Когда появляется алерт?

Comment: `filterKey` возвращает диапазон не `[0..33]`, у вас комментарий врёт

Comment: Я убрал букву Ё и по этому 32, а комментарий забыл исправить

Comment: И всё равно даже не `[0..32]`, а очень даже `[1040..1071]` :) Возможно, проблема не в этом, но я к тому, что врущие комментарии — это плохо. Устаревшая документация намного хуже отсутствия документации

Comment: Я имею вижу не вижу не диапазон, а алфавит без буквы Ё.

Comment: Ваш код труден для понимания и я не осилил его прочитать, но у меня он успешно переписался попроще и с возвращением буквы Ё и выдачей ожидаемого сързуё (правда, без мелкого регистра), может это вам поможет https://jsfiddle.net/gmss0rpp/

Comment: И, кстати, ваш код никак не сможет выдать сързуё, если вы и правда убрали из него букву ё :)

Comment: Ну буква ё отдельно от основных, на 1105 и 1025, по этому я ее убрал. Почему он с не может?

Comment: Предлагаю взять идею из моего примера (чуть обновлённая версия https://jsfiddle.net/gmss0rpp/1/) — там позиции символов берутся не из `charCodeAt`, а из позиции в переменной `alphabet`, и это очень сильно упрощает жизнь, особенно с этой несчастной Ё